# Which setting tells Resharper (with StyleCop) to not align ASP.Net controller attributes on one line?

Tags: resharper, stylecop

Example code:

```cs
[AllowAnonymous] [HttpPost("Register")] public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterParameters parameters)
```

How it should look like:

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("Register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterParameters parameters)
```

Which setting tells Resharper (with StyleCop) to not align ASP.Net controller attributes on one line, but on multiple? I didn't find the setting yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "Place method attribute on the same line". But it works only if you have another setting called "Keep existing arrangement of attributes" turned OFF.

Answer (score 1):

Additional Information to [Dmitry Osinovskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194020/dmitry-osinovskiy)'s answer:

1. **"Place method attribute on the same line"** can be found under **"C#"** → **"Formatting Style"** → **"Line Breaks and Wrapping"** → **"Arrangement of Attributes"** and needs to be set to **"Never"**:

[image]

2. **"Keep existing arrangement of attributes"** can be found under **"C#"** → **"Formatting Style"** → **"Line Breaks and Wrapping"** → **"Arrangement of Attributes"** and needs to be set to **"Off"** (No tick):

[image]